# D3 Range Based Filter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a D3 bar chart that would visualize a few ranges (massaged data already coming from somewhere else) and allow the user to select a number of ranges for filtering of their search criteria.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qear2g9b/

The mechanics of it work pretty well I think. The part I am running into problems with, is capturing user input and mapping it to the data.

Once finished, the user should be able to select and drag a range (along the x axis) for the categories they would like to see. I am using d3.brush to let the user select an area on the chart (I haven't looked into how to get it to select the entire chart height yet). On endbrush I am capturing coordinates that I need to map back to the categories that were on the x axis.

Since it is an ordinal scale, it doesn't have invert, so I am kind of suck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Code snippet below:

```
  function brushend() {
   console.log("BRUSH END");
   console.log(brush.extent());
   var pos = brush.extent();

   var out = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<pos.length;i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j<pos[i].length;j++) {
       console.log(pos[i][j] + " " + x.invert(pos[i][j])); // Doesn't work because x doesn't have invert method

     }

   }

  }
```